# Distance between words using NLP techniques

Tags: math, matrix, nlp

Given is a cluster of words such as {Berlin , BERLIN , BERlin, BeRlin,berlin,berliN , berLIN} . For some condition I have to treat these words as it is (cannot change to uniform case) . I have to select one . Is there any solution using NLP which can help me achieve this , for example select one which matches closest to the rest of the majority.

Thanks

Comment: "select one which matches closest to the rest of the majority", this open a sea of possibilities, can you elaborate more on that? maybe with a few examples.

Comment: Let me rephrase it , the cluster of words for example in this case is {Berlin , BERLIN , BERlin, BeRlin,berlin,berliN , berLIN} . Now I want to select one from it , based on correctness , similarity score to other words, readability score etc or it could be other parameters as well . But the point is selection from the above list . What possible options I have to solve this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Sorensen–Dice coefficient.

coefficientRatio = ((2*|X∩Y|) / (|X|+|Y|))

where,

|X| & |Y| are cardinalities of two sets,

|X∩Y| is number of common elements in both sets

The coefficient ranges from 0-1, with 1 being highly similar and 0 being least similar.

As you need the set to be case sensitive:

replace the chars in set with any symbols. (NOTE: using ascii values may 
drastically change the accuracy rate). I would recommend to encode the 
characters as different symbols to keep the accuracy intact.

eg: 

b='!', e='@', r='#', l='$', i='%', n='^',

B='&', E='*', R='(', L=')', I='?' , N='{'

code:-

```
var oldSet = ['Berlin' , 'BERLIN' , 'BERlin', 'BeRlin','berlin','berliN' , 'berLIN'];
var newSet = ['&@#$%^', '&*()?{', "&*($%^", "&@($%^", "!@#$%^", "!@#$%{", "!@#)?{"];

var ratio= [];

for(var i=0; i<newSet.length-1; i++) {
    for(var j=i+1; j<newSet.length; j++) {
        var cof= getCoefficient(newSet[i], newSet[j], getIntersection(newSet[i], newSet[j]));
        print("\n\n" + oldSet[i] + "====" + oldSet[j] + "===>" + cof);
        ratio.push(cof);        
    }
    print("\n");      
}

//This function will return coeffiecient between 0 to 1
function getCoefficient(x, y, commonCnt) {
    return ((2*commonCnt) / (x + y));
}
```

output:-

```
    Berlin====BERLIN===>0.16666666666666666


    Berlin====BERlin===>0.6666666666666666


    Berlin====BeRlin===>0.8333333333333334


    Berlin====berlin===>0.8333333333333334


    Berlin====berliN===>0.6666666666666666


    Berlin====berLIN===>0.3333333333333333




    BERLIN====BERlin===>0.5


    BERLIN====BeRlin===>0.3333333333333333


    BERLIN====berlin===>0


    BERLIN====berliN===>0.16666666666666666


    BERLIN====berLIN===>0.5




    BERlin====BeRlin===>0.8333333333333334


    BERlin====berlin===>0.5


    BERlin====berliN===>0.3333333333333333


    BERlin====berLIN===>0




    BeRlin====berlin===>0.6666666666666666


    BeRlin====berliN===>0.5


    BeRlin====berLIN===>0.16666666666666666




    berlin====berliN===>0.8333333333333334


    berlin====berLIN===>0.5




    berliN====berLIN===>0.6666666666666666
```